# Xamarin Studio exception when archiving for appstore

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am trying to archive a build for distribution to the app store but during the archive process I keep getting an exception popup from Xamarin Studio saying the following:

> "An error has occurred - Failed to archive app bundle. An empty string is not considered a valid value"

The exception occurs when it is signing the application:

```
'System.ArgumentException: An empty string is not considered a valid value.
  at System.Enum.Parse (System.Type enumType, System.String value, Boolean ignoreCase) [0x00081] in /private/tmp/source/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-3.2.3/mcs/class/corlib/System/Enum.cs:523 
  at System.Enum.Parse (System.Type enumType, System.String value) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-3.2.3/mcs/class/corlib/System/Enum.cs:453 
  at Xamarin.MacDev.PropertyListFormat+XmlFormat+Context.ReadObjectHead () [0x00001] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-monodevelop-4.0.13-branch/07afec66/source/md-addins/Xamarin.MacDev/PListObject.cs:1737 
  at Xamarin.MacDev.PropertyListFormat+XmlFormat+Context..ctor (System.Xml.XmlReader reader) [0x0000f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-monodevelop-4.0.13-branch/07afec66/source/md-addins/Xamarin.MacDev/PListObject.cs:1726 
  at Xamarin.MacDev.PropertyListFormat+XmlFormat.StartReading (System.IO.Stream input) [0x0008e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-monodevelop-4.0.13-branch/07afec66/source/md-addins/Xamarin.MacDev/PListObject.cs:1702 
  at Xamarin.MacDev.PropertyListFormat.CreateReadContext (System.IO.Stream input) [0x00019] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-monodevelop-4.0.13-branch/07afec66/source/md-addins/Xamarin.MacDev/PListObject.cs:1070 
  at Xamarin.MacDev.PDictionary.FromFile (System.String fileName, System.Boolean& isBinary) [0x00026] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-monodevelop-4.0.13-branch/07afec66/source/md-addins/Xamarin.MacDev/PListObject.cs:664 
  at Xamarin.MacDev.PDictionary.FromFile (System.String fileName) [0x00004] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-monodevelop-4.0.13-branch/07afec66/source/md-addins/Xamarin.MacDev/PListObject.cs:653 
  at MonoDevelop.IPhone.IPhoneProject.Archive (IProgressMonitor monitor, MonoDevelop.Projects.DotNetProjectConfiguration conf) [0x00111] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-monodevelop-4.0.13-branch/07afec66/source/md-addins/MonoDevelop.IPhone/MonoDevelop.IPhone/Project/IPhoneProject.cs:384'
```

Heres my bin\AppStore\iPhone\AppName.app\Info.plist

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>BuildMachineOSBuild</key>
    <string>11G63b</string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>ANet</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>ANetMobile</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
    <array>
      <string>logo_57.png</string>
      <string>logo_114.png</string>
      <string>logo_120.png</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.anet.anmobile</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>ANetMobile</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleResourceSpecification</key>
    <string>ResourceRules.plist</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.1</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleSupportedPlatforms</key>
    <array>
      <string>iPhoneOS</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>DTCompiler</key>
    <string>com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0</string>
    <key>DTPlatformBuild</key>
    <string>9B176</string>
    <key>DTPlatformName</key>
    <string>iphoneos</string>
    <key>DTPlatformVersion</key>
    <string>5.1</string>
    <key>DTSDKBuild</key>
    <string>9B176</string>
    <key>DTSDKName</key>
    <string>iphoneos5.1</string>
    <key>DTXcode</key>
    <string>0440</string>
    <key>DTXcodeBuild</key>
    <string>4F250</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
    <string>4.3</string>
    <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
    <array>
      <integer>1</integer>
    </array>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
      <string>armv6</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIStatusBarTintParameters</key>
    <dict>
      <key>UINavigationBar</key>
      <dict>
        <key>Style</key>
        <string>UIBarStyleDefault</string>
        <key>TintColor</key>
        <dict>
          <key>Blue</key>
          <real>1</real>
          <key>Green</key>
          <real>0.0</real>
          <key>Red</key>
          <real>0.0</real>
        </dict>
        <key>Translucent</key>
        <false/>
      </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: you might want to share your info.plist

Comment: Ok, I've added that above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xamarin has confirmed this is a bug in Studio, and will be fixed in 4.0.14 hotfix release.

Answer (score 0):

Are all of your fields filled in on the project options? Make sure you have app name filled in. I archived my ad-hoc distribution app this week with no problems.

Comment: Everything appears to be filled in on the settings, its at the 'signing application' stage that the exception occurs.

Comment: Maybe you should re-create your certificate/provisioning profile stuff and use the new one.

Comment: I've done that many times. I've submitted a bug to Xamarin, as it looks like .xcent file is corrupted when archive build. I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix this first:

```xml
<key>CFBundleSignature</key>
<string>????</string>
```

in your project options:

[image]

Try to set a valid bundle identifier.

Then, in order to build for the AppStore, you'll have to register this BundleIdentifier on Apple website

Comment: Hi Stephane, I posted this problem on Xamarin forum yesterday, and a contributor from TeamXamarin said that CFBundleSignature should be ????. However, as you suggested I have created an identifier with a bundle ID , and a certificate and profile, but still have the same problem.

Comment: Make sure your AppID/certificate/provisioning profile all have the same bundle indentifier (or that you are using a wildcard).

Comment: Waiting for result of bug report to Xamarin.